# Trying to create aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

I'm trying to create new aggregate function in PostgreSQL to use instead of the `sum()` function

I started my journey in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xaggr.html).

Since I wanted to create a function that takes an array of double precision values, sums them and then does some additional calculations I first created that final function:

```
takes double precision as input and gives double precision as output    
DECLARE
      v double precision;
BEGIN
      IF tax > 256 THEN
            v := 256;
      ELSE
            v := tax;
      END IF;
      RETURN v*0.21/0.79;
END;
```

Then I wanted to create the aggregate function that takes an array of double precision values and puts out a single double precision value for my previous function to handle.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE aggregate_ee_income_tax (float8[]) (
  sfunc = array_agg
 ,stype = float8
 ,initcond = '{}'
 ,finalfunc = eeincometax);
```

What I get when I run that command is:

> ERROR:  function array_agg(double precision, double precision[]) does
>   not exist

I'm somewhat stuck here, because the manual lists [array_agg()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) as existing function. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I run:

```
\da
                     List of aggregate functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Description 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

My installation has no aggregate functions at all? Or does only list user defined functions?

Basically what I'm trying to understand:

1) Can I use an existing functions to sum up my array values?

2) How can I find out about input and ouptut data types of functions? Docs claim that `array_agg()` takes any kind of input.

3) What is wrong with my own aggregate function?

#### Edit 1

To give more information and clearer picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have one huge query over several tables which goes something like this:

```
SELECT sum(tax) ... from (SUBQUERY) as foo group by id
```

I want to replace that sum function with my own aggregate function so I don't have to do additional calculations on backend - since they can all be done on database level.

#### Edit 2

Accepted Ants's answer. Since final solution comes from comments I post it here for reference:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE aggregate_ee_income_tax (float8)
(
 sfunc = float8pl
,stype = float8
,initcond = '0.0'
,finalfunc = eeincometax
);
```

Comment: I don't understand from your description why you can't just use `yourfinalfunc(sum(tax))` to transform the final result? this would avoid creating an aggregate function completely.

Comment: Because that query, which i referred to, is put together programmatically and if i were to add one function on top of another, then i would have to change alot in the process that puts the query together. Add bunch of conditions and whatnot - all that will make understanding the code much harder later on. So its easyer to just change the sum function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array agg is an aggregate function not a regular function, so it can't be used as a state transition function for a new aggregate. What you want to do is to create an aggregate function which has a state transition function that is identical to array_agg and a custom final func.

Unfortunately the state transition function of array_agg is defined in terms of an internal datatype so it can't be reused. Fortunately there is an existing function in core that already does what you want.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE aggregate_ee_income_tax (float8)(
    sfunc = array_append,
    stype = float8[],
    initcond = '{}',
    finalfunc = eeincometax);
```

Also note that you had your types mixed up, you probably want aggregate a set of floats to an array, not a set of arrays to a float.

Comment: Awesome. that gets me closer to what i want, but eeincometax finalfunc expects single float8 value not array. and array_append seems to only output array. So I still need to do the actual summing in my finalfunction or is there are core function, that outputs single value?

Comment: So you want as the state transition a function that takes two floats and returns the sum of those. Coincidentally this is what the + operator does. The function that implents + operator for float8's is called float8pl. Change the sfunc to float8pl and stype to float8 and you should be golden.

Comment: No i want aggregate function that takes bunch of records and sums them and then takes that sum and gives it to my finalfunc as input. Like i said - i want function to could replace sum() function in my query.

Comment: Yes, this is what it would do. float8pl as the transition function sums the values up and the final value is passed to your func. Also I forgot to mention that you need to change initcond to 0.0.

Comment: Awesome. At least i got through everything without errors. But value output seems to be wrong. Ill be debugging now :).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Ants excellent advice:

1.) Your final function could be simplified to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION eeincometax(float8)
  RETURNS float8 LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
SELECT (least($1, 256) * 21) / 79
$func$;
```

2.) It seems like you are dealing with money? In this case I would strongly advise to use the type [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) (preferred) or [`money`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-money.html) for the purpose. Floating point operations are often not precise enough.

3.) The initial condition of the aggregate can simply be just `0`:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE aggregate_ee_income_tax(float8)
(
  sfunc     = float8pl
 ,stype     = float8
 ,initcond  = 0
 ,finalfunc = eeincometax
);
```

4.) In your case `(least(sum(tax), 256) * 21) / 79` is probably faster than your custom aggregate. Aggregate functions provided by PostgreSQL are written in C and optimized for performance. I would use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for additional info. Just a question though - since my custom aggregate function relies of postgreSQL own float8pl function, which, as i understood from your post is also written in C and optimized - how much real overhead does my function add really?

Comment: @Zayatzz: Best to just test it. Run both variants with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) - maybe a couple of times to exclude cache effects. I'd be interested in the comparison ...